# How to solve and prevent many2one fields to become circular reference issue in odoo

Tags: odoo

in my module i forced to using many2one fields in most of models that have auto=true so too much fk in database created because of that then this fks Leading to circular reference issue and the real problems with this is the very slow and lag of performance with software when Several users working my question is how this problem can be sole if anyone can help me with this i really appreciate.
thanks in advance

i tried to reduce many2one fields but it wont solve problem

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent circular references, you may utilize the [`_check_recursion()`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/2ba6be20040a7b27d8cd8d95e089007a7a2edf78/odoo/models.py#L4460-L4483) helper to check for circular references in a hierarchical structure of records inside a Python constraint, and raise an error if a loop is detected, e.g.:

```py
@api.constrains('m2o_field')
def _check_m2o_field(self):
    if not self._check_recursion(parent='m2o_field'):
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(
            _('You cannot create recursive relationships.'))
```

`_check_recursion()` will return `False` if a loop is detected. You can pass the name of the *many-to-one* field to `_check_recursion()`, otherwise the value of the `_parent_name` class attribute will be used (which is [`parent_id`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/2ba6be20040a7b27d8cd8d95e089007a7a2edf78/odoo/models.py#L242) by default).

Answer (score 0):

To add a check preventing looping relations, add the following line to the
model:

```py
@api.constrains('parent_id')
def _check_hierarchy(self):
  if not self._check_recursion():
  raise models.ValidationError(
  'Error! You cannot create recursive categories.')
```

You should pass a specific many2one relation in `_check_recursion()` as a parameter if not a default `parent_id`.
I used `models.ValidationError` because i am working in Odoo-11 environment. But `_check_recursion()` method will prevent your hierarchical structure from infinite loop.